# rake aborted! for uninitialized constant that does exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I have built a rake task --

```
# SET RAKE TASK NAMESPACE
namespace :db do
# RAKE TASK DESCRIPTION
desc "Fetch property information and insert it into the database"

# RAKE TASK NAME    
task :insert_properties do

    # REQUIRE LIBRARIES
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'open-uri'

    # OPEN THE XML FILE
    mits_feed = File.open("app/assets/xml/mits.xml")

    # OUTPUT THE XML DOCUMENT
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(mits_feed)

    # FIND PROPERTIES OWNED BY NORTHSTEPPE AND CYCLE THORUGH THEM
    doc.xpath("//Property/PropertyID/Identification[@OrganizationName='northsteppe']").each do |property|

        # GATHER EACH PROPERTY'S INFORMATION
        information = {
            "street_address" => property.xpath("/Address/AddressLine1/text()"),
            "city" => property.xpath("/Address/City/text()"),
            "zipcode" => property.xpath("/Address/PostalCode/text()"),
            "short_description" => property.xpath("/Information/ShortDescription/text()"),
            "long_description" => property.xpath("Information/LongDescription/text()"),
            "rent" => property.xpath("/Information/Rents/StandardRent/text()"),
            "application_fee" => property.xpath("/Fee/ApplicationFee/text()"),
            "bedrooms" => property.xpath("/Floorplan/Room[@RoomType='Bedroom']/Count/text()"),
            "bathrooms" => property.xpath("/Floorplan/Room[@RoomType='Bathroom']/Count/text()"),
            "bathrooms" => property.xpath("/ILS_Unit/Availability/VacancyClass/text()")
        }


        # CREATE NEW PROPERTY WITH INFORMATION HASH CREATED ABOVE
        Property.create!(information)

    end # ENDS XPATH EACH LOOP

end # ENDS INSERT_PROPERTIES RAKE TASK

end # ENDS NAMESAPCE DECLARATION
```

when I run "rake db:insert_properties" this is the error I produce --

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Property
/Users/stevejobs/Sites/nsrosu/lib/tasks/property_information.rake:39:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:237:in `block in each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:236:in `upto'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:236:in `each'
/Users/stevejobs/Sites/nsrosu/lib/tasks/property_information.rake:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:insert_properties
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have a Property model with a table set up to accept all of these attributes, so why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your rake task needs to boot the Rails environment prior to running.  That way you can access the classes.

To do this, you need to run the `environment` task.  To make this happen, change your task definition to

```
task :insert_properties => :environment do
```

Comment: when I do this I get this error "rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'enviroment'"

Comment: Is it possible I have the rake file in the wrong folder? It is currently located in "/lib/tasks/property_information.rake"